# How does an XOR phase difference detector behave when input frequencies are different?

Tags: analog, signal, math, phase

How does an XOR phase difference detector such as AD8302 behave when input frequencies are different? Does it give meaningful results when the frequencies are close but different? Is there a simple description of the phase detection error vs the difference in frequencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the two inputs to an XOR phase detector are at different frequencies, it behaves as a frequency mixer, with a nominally zero mean output.

It's only when the two inputs are the same frequency that you can meaningfully talk about a phase difference for them. The XOR then has a non-zero output which represents the phase difference of the two signals, at least over a half cycle.

Fortunately for PLL designers, the output when the input frequencies are different is not useless. Fed back into the PLL, the varying output of the XOR causes a frequency modulation of the VCO, which modulates the XOR output frequency. This FM causes the mean XOR output to move slightly away from zero, which will alter the mean VCO frequency via the PLL. As long as the output frequency of the XOR is less than the loop bandwidth of the PLL, each successive cycle of frequency modulation will nudge the VCO frequency towards the reference frequency. The effect is small, but if the loop has the range, it will eventually capture under these conditions. Often, the users of the loop are impatient for speed, and so other faster methods will be used to obtain lock, but if time is not of the essence, an XOR can be used by itself to lock a PLL.

Comment: I am not trying to design PLLs. I am trying to detect the phase change of an input with respect to a reference signal. If what you say is true, then it is impossible to do that with an XOR phase detector alone without a PLL, since the two inputs always have some frequency instability. However, how can the mean output be zero if the XOR detector only outputs 0 and 1? Shouldn't the mean value be somewhere in between?

Comment: @DeskReference If outputs are +1 and -1, then the mean is zero. If they're 0 and 1, then the mean is 0.5. Frequency difference is not the same as frequency instability. If you're concerned about the effect on a phase detector, then the question is 'what is the instantaneous phase difference between the two signals?' The XOR PSD can handle only half a cycle range. There are other types of phase detector which can handle a whole cycle, or two cycles, or more, depending on the phase jitter due to the frequency instability. I mentioned PLL as that must handle both frequency and phase differences

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It helps a lot. My concern is that the frequency instability in the inputs will naturally lead to a frequency difference between them, causing momentary error in the phase difference measurements. I was just wondering how large an error I can expect.

Comment: In the case of two inputs with nominally the same frequency but varying phase, all the phase measurements will be accurate as long as the relative phase does not exceed the range of the PSD. In the XOR case this is half a cycle. A change of phase between two successive measurements can be interpretted as a frequency difference, frequency = dPhase/dTime. We tend to call this instability or jitter if the phase difference between the two is bounded. If the dPhase exceeds the PSD range, and repeatedly exceeds it again and again in the same direction, then that's a frequency difference.

Comment: Then would the long-term oscillator frequency drift (the ones measured in ppm) result in phase errors?

Comment: @DeskReference What **exactly** is your measurement application? There's a lot of technology (aka knowhow) around phase measurement that I can help you with, but it's very domain specific, and it would be a waste of my time to go on at length about one domain, when you are trying to work in another.

Comment: XOR is often the wrong PSD to choose, but for PLLs, if can be the right one, hence my jumping to conclusions about what you needed. Phase is the integral of frequency, which some folks find hard to think through. The constant of integration is yours to choose, but when, why and how? Sometimes phase is what we want, sometimes it's a way to compute frequency stability, which is yours? There are many other types of phase detector, most are better in for measurement than XOR, sometimes for range reasons, sometimes for measurement quality. What's a phase error, is it slightly wrong, or broken?

Comment: Ah OK. My system is for biosensing purposes. An RF signal (hundreds of MHz) enters a system that works as a phase shifter. Due to the change in the properties of the system, the phase difference between the input and output changes over time (several degrees per second). I think an XOR detector is appropriate in this case. I understand that my previous questions about frequency drift is not warranted, as the frequency drift will apply to both input and output.

Comment: If it's for always sensing the difference between a stimulus and a return signal, then the phase shift will obviously be bounded. Whether or not it crosses the point where the XOR slope changes from +1 to -1 is another matter. You may want to include a settable delay between the two channels so you can always sit the phase variation range in the middle of one of the two constant slopes. You can choose to interpret 'several degrees per second' as a frequency difference, but because you know it's caused by a phase shift, and the total shift is bounded, it's not going to cause a problem of itself

Answer (score 3):

You will get an XOR signal that is a PWM that reflects the running phase difference between the two. The PWM will modulate from 0-100% at the rate of the frequency difference.

For example, if the frequencies differ by 10Hz, you will see the XOR be a PWM at the average of the two sample rates, with a linear duty cycle sweep from 0-100-0% that repeats every 100ms. Integrating this XOR output will yield a triangle waveform.

Simulate it here: [Falstad Sim of XOR PLL](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcA2aYDMZIA5nrzgEzYCcIySlkAUGAtiACzqEiGGNPKfuc0DGIBMTYchIwgmRQoseJAgBaQtEJgS6BCW0cw7AOwJqAJ3ENiDLawszG8E2ZAtIQkq2cys86gHdX17Es3J0IXGgBzfxCXKydhKFoETjBGZODJaXVWF2yhagAlcFTwfWlsFzBSmVZkHOgkFSQw+t8inhw26IS-FM4PZndQhNMM8GCPLJkEe0EJ8aHeGRh5SDIwaGx0VLcBuxIpfX1WgbHWE8WaAHlOjxJpDzDqAEM41j0GE-eQNaRFOnAVhV6sR9MQ7HgSJBGNgwAx1sJsPpmMgNMgkUl6ADvH45oMKnpul0wATNG8CTQcfFeq9ToTSbTPsEKUwWAzWV8aKYPItuaDPPZIry8WxAgkAPYgfTkPhMYkxWTyEilKSSaqSpzUCUYaW2OVCBXwJUUZCqiqa8AQbi2VZkFTodDYOyEZDqUEkVKMJpyFIu6ZgPD6e2rSDocBsC0aoA)

Comment: What about the average of the triangle waveform? Does it give any meaningful value? Is it still sensitive to phase changes of the input?

Comment: Without feedback (that is, fixed-but-different input frequencies) the average will be zero. With feedback (e.g., from the VCO) there will be a bias that, with enough VCO pull-in range, nudges the frequency and phase to lock.

Comment: I updated the sim to include a VCO as a complete PLL so you can observe the pull-in behavior.